# I need to modify query for adding a filter

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help,  I need to add a filter - from and to date. On the column tran_log.Tran_Date in the query given below. Please help me with the updated query.

```
SELECT 
  tran_log.FROM_CRN, 
  ktk_log.DEBIT_ACCT_NO, 
  ktk_log.TXN_AMOUNT, 
  ktk_log.EXT_SYSTEM || '-' || ktk_log.REFRENCE_NO AS "Kotak bank ref 
 number", 
   case when ktk_log.RETURN_CODE_STATUS = 0 then 'SUC' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS 
"Status", 
  ktk_log.DEBIT_CREDIT_FLAG As "Transaction code", 
   ktk_log.ERROR_CODE, 
  KTK_LOG.APP_TYPE as "Merchant code", 
  tran_log.Tran_Date "Transaction_Date", 
  tran_log.SOURCE_REF_NO As "Merchant reference number" 
FROM 
  KTK_TRANSACTION_LOG ktk_log 
  INNER JOIN transaction_log tran_log on TRAN_LOG.TRAN_REF_NO = 
KTK_LOG.EXT_SYSTEM || '-' || KTK_LOG.REFRENCE_NO;
```

Comment: add the condition  `where tran_log.Tran_Date >= DATE ? AND  tran_log.Tran_Date  < DATE ?` where `?` can be some date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format within quotes, for eg:- `DATE '2019-06-20'`

Comment: You mean something like... `WHERE tran_log.Tran_Date BETWEEN to_date('01-JUN-2019') AND to_date('10-JUN-2019')`

Answer (score 0):

I THINK THIS COULD BE HELPFUL

> SELECT * FROM TABLE
>   WHERE tran_log BETWEEN FRMDATE AND TODATE;

Answer (score 0):

What is your actual question?

- How to filter query results? Use a `WHERE` clause.
- Whether to put the condition in a `WHERE` clause or extend your `ON` clause? Just decide. Both methods are equally okay. Extending the `ON` clause would have the advantage that you could change the inner join to an outer join more easily, if you ever want to do that.
- How to use date literals? That's `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'`, e.g. `DATE '2019-06-20'`.
- How to compare dates? In Oracle there is no difference betwen a date and a datetime. The `DATE` datatype allows for a time with the date. So it is often preferred to use `>=` and `<` when checking against a date range. E.g. for April: `where mydate >= date '2019-04-01' and mydate < '2019-05-01'`. Thus you get everything from the first till the last nanosecond :-)